# How to fix aHg output encoding?

Tags: emacs, mercurial

Here is what I use:
- MacOS X 10.6.7
- GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)
- Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.7.2+20101201)
- GNU Emacs 24.0.50 (build from git repo with --cocoa flag)
- aHg v0.99

Here is my emacs settings:

```
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(setq locale-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-selection-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-language-environment 'UTF-8)
```

And here if what i got after `C-c h g s`:

```
parent: 2512:6252abcd7368 tip
 JavaScript: ???????? ???????????? ????? ? ???????.
branch: default
commit: 3 modified, 6 unknown
update: (current)
```

Running `hg log` under `M-x term` gives me a correct result I can read (`?` is a russian chars...). So... How can I fix this in Emacs in aHg output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, that should be checked here - which `LANG` is set when Emacs was started)? (what is returned when you execute `M-: (getenv "LANG")`? As I remember, Mac OS X set LANG to "C" on the start of launchpad... setting of language environment don't modify LANG...

You can explicitly set the LANG environment from Emacs using `(setenv "LANG" "ru_RU.UTF-8")` or use "en_EN.UTF-8" if it preferable.

P.S. I just checked ahg with different LANG settings, and see question marks when I set LANG to "C", and see Russian letters when I run `ahg-log` in repository

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the default font that is being used for output when you do <kbd>C-c h g s</kbd> doesn't support Cyrillic characters. You can see what font is being used by placing the point on one of the Russian characters that isn't being displayed properly and pressing <kbd>C-u C-x =</kbd>. To ensure that Russian is always displayed properly in Emacs, you can specify that all Russian characters will be displayed in a particular font. Since the Cyrillic characters are in the Unicode range U+0400 – U+04FF and the Arial font seems to display these characters ok, you could try the following in your Emacs init file:

```
(set-fontset-font "fontset-default"
                  '(#x400 . #x4ff)
                  "Arial")
```

Comment: usually, if font doesn't support some characters, then empty boxes are drawn, not question marks...

Comment: Yes, but it wasn't clear to me whether that was the "actual" output or whether the poster was just putting "?" characters where the expected Russian characters should appear.

Comment: This is actual output - I just copy/paste it from the terminal.